# EJBCLIENT000025: No EJB receiver available for handling, how to fix?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, intellij-idea, ejb, wildfly

I'm creating a simple client-server Java EE application with EJB, using IntelliJ IDEA 2016 and WildFly 10.

I've created a new [Java EE Project](http://s32.postimg.org/3re6cwmjp/ejb_struct.png) *EJB_final_test* and added two modules:

- Java module *EJB_test_client*
- EJB module *EJB_test_server*

Then I [set artifact](http://postimg.org/image/vkmm10fq9/) as Java EE Application Archive which creates an *EJBTestEAR.ear* file for *EJB_test_server* module.

I've deployed this EAR file on WildFly server. Server runs well and it successfully deploys the artifact on start up.

Here is my *jboss-ejb-client.properties* file:

```
remote.connections=default
remote.connection.default.host=localhost
remote.connection.default.port=8180
remote.connection.default.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOANONYMOUS=false
remote.connection.default.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOPLAINTEXT=false
```

Here is my code for only class `ClientTest` in *EJB_test_client* module:

```
package test;

import facade.TestFacadeBeanRemote;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import java.util.Properties;

public class ClientTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Properties jndiProperties = new Properties();
        jndiProperties.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
        Context ctx = new InitialContext(jndiProperties);
        TestFacadeBeanRemote remote = (TestFacadeBeanRemote) ctx.lookup("ejb:EJBTestEAR/EJB_test_server//TestFacadeBean!facade.TestFacadeBeanRemote");

        System.out.println(remote.tstPlus("Hello", "World"));
    }

}
```

Here is code for classes `TextExecutiveBean, TestFacadeBean, TestFacadeBeanRemote` which are all in module EJB_test_server:

- *TestExecutiveBean* class:

  ```
  package executive;

  import javax.ejb.LocalBean;
  import javax.ejb.Stateless;

  @Stateless
  @LocalBean
  public class TestExecutiveBean {

      public String doPlusOperation(String str1, String str2) {
          return str1 + " " + str2 + " " + str1;
      }
  }
  ```
- *TestFacadeBean* class:

  ```
  package facade;

  import javax.ejb.EJB;
  import javax.ejb.Stateless;
  import executive.TestExecutiveBean;

  @Stateless
  public class TestFacadeBean implements TestFacadeBeanRemote {

      @EJB
      private TestExecutiveBean test2;

      public String tstPlus(String str1, String str2) {
          return test2.doPlusOperation(str1, str2);
      }
  }
  ```
- *TestFacadeBeanRemote* interface:

  ```
  package facade;

  import javax.ejb.Remote;

  @Remote
  public interface TestFacadeBeanRemote {

      public String tstPlus(String str1, String str2);
  }
  ```

When I'm trying to run `ClientTest` main method, which tries to communicate with server for finding `tstPlus()` method in *EJBTestEAR*, I'm getting the following exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   EJBCLIENT000025: **No EJB receiver available for handling**
>   [appName:EJBTestEAR, moduleName:EJB_test_server, distinctName:]
>   combination for invocation context
>   org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext@184f6be2  at
>   org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext.requireEJBReceiver(EJBClientContext.java:798)
>     at
>   org.jboss.ejb.client.ReceiverInterceptor.handleInvocation(ReceiverInterceptor.java:128)
>     at
>   org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:186)
>     at
>   org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.sendRequestWithPossibleRetries(EJBInvocationHandler.java:255)
>     at
>   org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:200)
>     at
>   org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:183)
>     at
>   org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:146)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.tstPlus(Unknown Source)    at
>   test.ClientTest.main(ClientTest.java:20)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)

Please, how can I fix this error? Am I doing something wrong? Is configuration of my artifact which I deploy on the server right?

Comment: I'd suggest you to drop the `ejb:` lookup approach and use `http-remoting` instead. For that, you should also have `jndiProperties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");`, `jndiProperties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "http-remoting://127.0.0.1:8180");` and `jndiProperties.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", true);`. Then, the lookup should be made to the JNDI name relative to `java:jboss/exported` namespace.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for an answer. Is this good aproach also if I'm using local remote? And please could you briefly explain what should I change in my code? Should I still create .ear file and deploy it on the server? And I dont understand the last sentence about lookup with JNDI name relative to java:jboss/exported, could you please explain further or give an example for my code?

Comment: Did you try with `8080` port? Also create application user and add these properties: `remote.connection.default.username=user  

remote.connection.default.password=password`.

Comment: @aribeiro - Why would you suggest that?

Comment: @Dave well I had bad experiences using the `ejb:` approach that's why I'm not fond of it even though that's the "procedure" example [given](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/EJB+invocations+from+a+remote+client+using+JNDI) by JBoss. Nevertheless, I believe a combination between both is the best approach, as mentioned [here](https://blog.akquinet.de/2014/09/26/jboss-eap-wildfly-three-ways-to-invoke-remote-ejbs/).